# Identify data type when express-flash() give Toastr

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs

I want to make Toastr flash message for me when it have success-error-info from flash() to let user know error input, or success add new data
and instead of write message in everyfile, i want write in layout
but Im not really sure how to write correctly the data-type of the div to ejs know when it have data-type or not
so i need some advices, thank you
this is my **Layout.ejs** .

```
  <div style="display: none;" id="toast-message" data-type="info | success | error">
    <%= messages.(info | success | error) %> 
  </div>

 <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('....start toast....')

        const type = $('#toast-message').data('type')
        const message = $('#toast-message').text()
        console.log('data ', type, message)

        if (type != '' && message != '') {
          console.log('show toast...')
          toastr[type](message);
        }
      })
    </script>
```

For Example Error Case with

```
<div style="display: none;" id="toast-message" data-type="error">
    Error
</div>
```

[image: My example for error case]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out the work sollution not the optimized
for Server site when req.flash() return 'success' or 'error'

```
if (req.body.name.length > 0 && req.body.password.length > 8) {
      req.flash('success', 'Add New Successful');
      const rs = await user.save();
      if (rs) {
        res.redirect('/member/list');
      }
    } else {
      req.flash('error', 'Name is required and Password must greater than 8 characters');
      res.redirect('/member/new');
    }
```

and for Layout.ejs

```
 <!-- toast message -->
  <%   let x,y=""
    if(messages.success){
    y = "success"
    x = messages.success
   } else if(messages.info){
     y ="info"
     x = messages.info
   } else if (messages.error){
     y = "error"
     x = messages.error
   } %>

  <div style="display: none;" id="toast-message" data-type="<%=y%>">
    <%=x%>
  </div>
  <!-- end toast-->
```